# ICryptoTransform.TransformFinalBlock vs ICryptoTransform.TransformBlock

Tags: .net

I am Learning cryptography in .net, why method 1 works while 2 fired argument exception.
See [Symmetric Algorithm exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2006394/symmetric-algorithm-exception)
for a complete code

1- ICryptoTransform.TransformFinalBlock

2- ICryptoTransform.TransformBlock

Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should be using a [CryptoStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.cryptostream.aspx), which will automatically call the correct `ICryptoTransform` methods.

For example:

```
var stream = new MemoryStream();
using (var transform = symAlgo.CreateEncryptor())
using (var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(stream, transform, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
using (var writer = new StreamWriter(cryptoStream))
    writer.Write(someString);

byte[] cipherBytes = stream.ToArray();
```