# AES decryption The input data is not a complete block

Tags: c#, encryption, aes

I'm trying to encrypt a `string` and decript it using `AES`. The encryption worked fine but I'm getting an error of `The input data is not a complete block` for the decryption. Is there an issue with my padding?

```
var aes = System.Security.Cryptography.Aes.Create();
aes.GenerateKey();
aes.GenerateIV();
aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;

var desEncrypter = aes.CreateEncryptor();
var buffer = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(text);

finalV = Convert.ToBase64String(desEncrypter.TransformFinalBlock(buffer, 0, buffer.Length));

var desDecrypter = aes.CreateDecryptor();
var buff = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(finalV);

var origValue = desDecrypter.TransformFinalBlock(buff , 0, buff .Length);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're creating `finalV` by converting bytes to Base64. In order to turn that back into bytes, you need to call `Convert.FromBase64String(finalV)`.

You're calling `ASCII.GetBytes(finalV)`, which gets you the bytes representing that Base64 text, rather than the original bytes.

**EDIT**

Not sure where you're getting stuck, but here is working code that is based on yours, so you can diff this out and see where you're getting the error:

```
string text = "ABC";

var aes = System.Security.Cryptography.Aes.Create();
aes.GenerateKey();
aes.GenerateIV();
aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;

var desEncrypter = aes.CreateEncryptor();
var buffer = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(text);

var finalV = Convert.ToBase64String(desEncrypter.TransformFinalBlock(buffer, 0, buffer.Length));

var desDecrypter = aes.CreateDecryptor();
var buff = Convert.FromBase64String(finalV);

var origValue = desDecrypter.TransformFinalBlock(buff, 0, buff.Length);
string result = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(origValue);
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Comment: Thank you I have fixed this. Now I can convert the decrypted value to a `byte[]`. I cannot seem to convert this into a `string` though.  I tried calling `System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString()` which should take in a `byte[]` yet I'm still getting this error.

Comment: Your `buff` doesn't have any meaning as a string. It's the encypted text. Assuming your encryption code is ok, then `origValue` represents your decrypted value. Assuming that was originally a string, that's the one you need to call: `string decryptedText = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(origValue)`.

Comment: yes I have tried this but I get the message `cannot implicitly convert from string to byte[]`. I printed the type of `origValue` to verify before and it is `System.byte[]` I don't know where the type error might be coming from.

Comment: Also, I'd look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2006922/111266) for better code for simple encryption of a string.